# Join the same table to identify differences in records

Tags: sql, join

I have a table that is updated every day where new data is inserted/appended underneath the previous day's data. I want to find the difference in data between the 2 dates.

| ID_number | daily_date | account_number | customer_description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12-26-2022 | 34 | description1 |
| 2 | 12-26-2022 | 42 | description2 |
| 3 | 12-26-2022 | 12 | description3 |
| 4 | 12-27-2022 | 34 | description1 |
| 5 | 12-27-2022 | 42 | description2 |
| 6 | 12-27-2022 | 99 | description3 |

The idea is to only return the last line I have in the table, which is the only line of data that is not a copy from the previous day.

I wrote the code here:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table1 t2 ON (t1.id_number = t2.id_number)
WHERE t1.id_number IS NULL
```

This code returns no values, it's just empty. Does that mean I have no differences in the records on those 2 days or does the code not work? I'm not sure how to verify. Also, new records are appended every day to the same table, so I only want the difference between the current date and the day before. Would I write something like:

```
"WHERE daily_date is CURDATE() and daily_date is CURDATE()-1" or something like that?
```

Comment: The join will definitely find a `t1.id_number = t2.id_number` row (the same row matching itself), so `t1.id_number IS NULL` will never be true. The query as you have written it will never return anything. Can you provided a table showing expected output (what you want returned for your sample data above)?

Comment: The table with the expected output would just have 1 row in the new table, which is the last row in the table above (row#6) because that's the only record that is different

Comment: Is the difference because account_number=99 doesn't exist for 12-26-2022, or because the third row for 12-27-2022 doesn't match the third row for 12-26-2022? Either way, why isn't the account number 12 row different?

Comment: it's because account_number=99 doesn't exist

Comment: And why isn't the account number 12 row also included? It's different (no longer exists).

Comment: And what if the account number is the same, but the description is different? Do you need to handle differences other than new account numbers?

Comment: Also, can you confirm the DBMS is MySQL? (things like `curdate()` will be different depending on whether this is MySQL, SQL Server, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not overly familiar whether you can join a table to itself, but can't you just query with the date filter set to the past two days?

Something like below;

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE date_daily BETWEEN GETDATE()-1 AND GETDATE()
ORDER BY account_number
```

Answer (score 0):

You used `id_number` instead of `account_number`, which is why no data is returned. Additionally, you need to specify which dates are `t1` and `t2`.

Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table1 t2 
ON t1.account_number = t2.account_number
AND t1.daily_date = '12-27-2022'
AND t2.daily_date = '12-26-2022'
WHERE t2.id_number IS NULL
```